# Smallest order of group to have non abelian proper subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the smallest order for a group to have a non abelian proper subgroups?  Is there any efficient method to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

You want to minimize the index $[G:H]$, so the smallest size for $|G|$ can be $2 |H|$. This situation exists, for example $H \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. The smallest non abelian group is $S_3$, so the minimal size of a group with non abelian subgroup is $12$, like $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Then it should be $$S_4$$ as $$S_3$$ has all subgroups as abelian one.

Comment: You misunderstand, $S_3 \subset S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not abelian.